# Apache2 Proxy server

Tags: mod-proxy, apache2.2

Lately I encountered some issues with apache2's proxy server.
I set `ProxyRequests` to `On` yesterday evening not knowing what it did.
When I tried accessing my webhost this evening it was very slow and unstable.
I checked the access log and saw alot of IP addresses were trying to connect to my server.

After some searching I found out `ProxyRequests On` was causing the issue and I disabled it.
Now my local proxies are working just fine and everything works as it should.

There are just 2 question I'd like an answer to:
What does `ProxyRequests On` do exacly and how did all these ip addresses know there was a proxy server running on my server?

~ Archcry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProxyRequests On` enables your server as a proxy server. Do not enable proxying with ProxyRequests until you have secured your server. 
If you only use reverse proxy, keep `ProxyRequests off`.

There are lot of scan tools can detect a proxy server and may use your server to proxy there requests, maybe do bad things.